# Multiple VMs mounting and writing on the same partition

Tags: virtual-machines, xen, ext4

I have multiple VMs ( XEN domains ) which are getting data and writing it on a directory in a ext4 partition. Is this going to introduce data loss or corruption?

Comment: Quite possibly, if you're not using samba or NFS or a cluster-aware FS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I'm assuming you're not using NFS, since you don't mention it and you do mention ext4. If you care about your data, you need to use NFS or something like GFS - a multi-initiator filesystem - as NickW says. The ext4 filesystem can only handle one initiator. I'm surprised you were able to boot your second system and make the mount properly, actually.